# Flow: make a key from an imported object type optional

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to import a random object from an external module and use their flow type:

```
export type randomType = {
    a: string,
    b: boolean
}
```

I want to import the randomType to my library but I want to make b optional

```
import { randomType } from 'randomModule';
// pseudo flow code:
type shrinkedRandomType = randomType - {b: boolean}
// How can I make this in flow so it equals this?
type shrinkedRandomType = {
    a: string,
    b?: boolean
}
// or even 
type shrinkedRandomType = {
    a: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The spread operator to the rescue!

If you are unfamiliar with the spread operator, [look it up on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Otherwise, the way to do it would be as follows:

```
type randomType = {
    a: string,
    b: boolean
}

type shrinkedRandomType = {
    ...randomType,
    b?: boolean
}

// Perfectly valid
let test:shrinkedRandomType = {
 a: "Hi"
}
```

Comment: Hello, sorry but it does'nt work the way I want. if ```let test:shrinkedRandomType = {
 a: "Hi"
}``` is valid is not important. I want {a:"hi", b:"hello"} not to be valid

Comment: What do you care about then?

Comment: I want {a:"hi", b:"hello"} not to be valid without creating a new type from scratch

Comment: I see. Change it to b?: undefined then